# Capitalizing a single word out of a sentence

Tags: java

Right what i need it to do is to capitalize the searched for word from each line, so I already have `

```
    File myFile = new File("AliceInWonderland.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    int count = 0;

    ArrayList<String> Alice = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Select the word that you would like to search for, from the book of alice and wonderland: ");
        word = uInput.next();


    while(scan.hasNext()){
        Alice.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

    for(int i = 0;i <= Alice.size();i++){
        if(Alice.get(i).contains(word)){
            System.out.println(Alice.get(i));
            count++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(Alice.get(i));
        }
    }`
```

I could write `System.out.println(Alice.get(i).ToUpper);` but this would capitalize all lines with searched for word in it and all i want to do is highlight the searched for words

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop such as

```
for(int i = 0;i <= Alice.size();i++)          
{             
  if(Alice.get(i).contains(word))
  {
     System.out.println(word.toupperCase());

     count++;
  }
  else
 {
      System.out.println(Alice.get(i));
   }
}
```

While you know the word which need to be capitalized, why do get the string from the file and capitalize it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to upcase the word within a string:

```
private static String capWord(String s, String w) {
    int k = s.indexOf(w);
    if (k < 0)
        return s;
    return s.substring(0, k) + w.toUpper() + s.substring(k + w.length());
}
```

Use it here:

```
System.out.println(capWord(Alice.get(i), word));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int wordLength = word.length();
    for(int i = 0;i < Alice.size();i++){
        if(Alice.get(i).contains(word)){
            for(int c=0;c<Alice.get(i).length()-wordLength;c++){
                if(Alice.get(i).substring(c, c+wordLength).equals(word)){
                    System.out.print(Alice.get(i).substring(0, c));
                    System.out.print(Alice.get(i).substring(c, c+wordLength).toUpperCase());
                    System.out.print(Alice.get(i).substring(c+wordLength, Alice.get(i).length()) + "\n");
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(Alice.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the reading loop to this:

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    Alice.add(scan.next());
}
```

Using `next` instead of `nextLine` reads the next word, instead of the next line.

However, if you want to preserve the line breaks, you could also do:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    line = scan.nextLine();

    for (String w : line.split(" "))
        Alice.add(w);
}
```

Now when searching for the word, you can use the `equals` method to find the exact word, or `equalsIgnoreCase` if you want to ignore the word case. Here is how it would look with `equals`:

```
for(String w : Alice){
    if(w.equals(word)) {
        System.out.print(w.toUpperCase());
        count++;        
    } else
        System.out.print(w);
```

Also, you could avoid the intermediate List and work on the line as you read it. Something like this:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    line = scan.nextLine();

    for (String w : line.split(" "))
        if(w.equals(word)) {
            System.out.print(w.toUpperCase());
            count++;        
        } else
            System.out.print(w);
}
```

**EDIT:** I didn't take into account that the last word on the line may be the word you are looking for; in that case, since is the last word, it will include the line break ("\n"), hence it won't match to `w.equals(word)`. For tackling this problem down, you can use the `matches` method instead of `equals`. `matches` takes a regular expresion, so you could replace the if expression in the examples for:

```
if (w.matches(word + "\s*")){
    ...
}
```

The `\s` is a predefined regex match group that will match any whitespace, including `\n`, and the `*` is for matching 0 or more of this.